# drag and drop functionality for a tree in table using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a tree in a table. I would like to know how to add drag and drop functionality to the below tree using angularjs. Any help would be much appreciated. Plunkr added [click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/UBdmhH2dd1GnlJ0wMCAz?p=preview).

// html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1>
  Tree Table and Checkbox with AngularJS
</h1>
<hr>
<div class="wrapper" data-ng-app="testApp" data-ng-controller="treeTable">
  <table class="table-nested">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <!-- <th >
          <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" />
        </th> -->
        <th>
         <input data-ng-checked="(list | selected).length == list.length" data-ng-click="toggleAllCheckboxes($event)" type="checkbox" /> Name
        </th>
        <th class="cell-members">
          Version
        </th>
        <th>
          Size
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="newRepo" style="font-size:12px" data-ng-class="{opened: item.opened}" data-ng-include="&#39;table_tree.html&#39;" data-ng-repeat="item in list"></tbody>
  </table>
  <script id="table_tree.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <tr ng-class="{parent: item.children}" ng-init="parentScope = $parent.$parent; initCheckbox(item, parentScope.item)">

      <td class="cell-name" ng-if="level &amp;&amp; level &gt; 1">
      <span style="padding-left: 30px" >&nbsp;  <input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{item.name}} </span>
      </td>
<td class="cell-name top-border" ng-if=" &#40;&#33;level &amp;&amp; level &lt;&#61; 1 &#41; &#124;&#124 &#40;level &amp;&amp; level &lt;&#61; 1&#41;">
        <span style="padding-left:11px" ng-click="item.opened = !item.opened"></span>&nbsp;<input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{item.name}}
      </td>

<td class="cell-name top-border" ng-if="&#33;level">
       <span class="indent" ng-click="item.opened = !item.opened"></span>&nbsp;<input ng-change="toggleCheckbox(item, parentScope)" ng-model="item.selected" type="checkbox" />
        {{item.name}}
      </td>

      <td class="cell-members top-border">
        {{item.Version}} 
      </td>
      <td>
        {{item.Size}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="children" ng-if="item.children &amp;&amp; item.children.length &gt; 0">
      <td colspan="3">
        <table>
          <tbody style="font-size:12px" ng-class="{opened: item.opened}" ng-include="&#39;table_tree.html&#39;" ng-init="level = level + 1" ng-repeat="item in item.children"></tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this directive, after trying several of them, I've found that this one is quite flexible, and I've used it successfully in one of my projects:

[Angular Drag and Drop](http://angular-dragdrop.github.io/angular-dragdrop/)